# Unable to find json path from an array

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am new to JSON. I have a LossHistory Json from which I need to filter "LineOfBusinessCode" equal to "General Liab - Excess" from that I need to show specific "Lossyear"
My JSON data

```
{"LossHistory": {
  "LossDetails": [
    {
      "LineOfBusinessCode": "General Liab - Excess",
      "Lossyear": 2018,
      "NumberOfTotalClaims": 8,
      "PaidLosses": 500,
      "PaidExpense": 80000,
      "Outstandingreserve": 800,
      "TotalIncurred": 800,
      "valuationDate": "2023-12-06T00:00:00",
      "LargeClaim": 700,
      "NumberOfOpenClaims": 6,
      "carrierName": "Hrst",
      "ClaimSource": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "LineOfBusinessCode": "General Liab - Excess",
      "Lossyear": 2019,
      "NumberOfTotalClaims": 8,
      "PaidLosses": 500,
      "PaidExpense": 80000,
      "Outstandingreserve": 800,
      "TotalIncurred": 800,
      "valuationDate": "2023-12-06T00:00:00",
      "LargeClaim": 700,
      "NumberOfOpenClaims": 6,
      "carrierName": "Hrst",
      "ClaimSource": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "LineOfBusinessCode": "Auto",
      "Lossyear": 2018,
      "NumberOfTotalClaims": 8,
      "PaidLosses": 500,
      "PaidExpense": 80000,
      "Outstandingreserve": 800,
      "TotalIncurred": 800,
      "valuationDate": "2023-12-06T00:00:00",
      "LargeClaim": 700,
      "NumberOfOpenClaims": 6,
      "carrierName": "Hrst",
      "ClaimSource": "Manual"
    }
  ]
}}
```

my path

```
$..LossDetails[?(@.LineOfBusinessCode == 'General Liab - Excess')].Lossyear
```

now my result is

```
[
   2018,
   2019
]
```

I'm getting as expected now I need 2018 or 2019 any one of them. We can use index or anyother way but we need to go with this condition LineOfBusinessCode is equal to "General Liab - Excess" then lossyear
expected output

```
2018
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272), it is impossible just use `JsonPath` to achieve it in one line syntax. But you can just get the result and then `get(0)` to get it easily ,such as:

```
String filterResult = JsonPath.read(fullJson, "$..LossDetails[?(@.LineOfBusinessCode == 'General Liab - Excess')]").toJSONString();
int lossYear = JsonPath.read(filterResult, "$[0].Lossyear");
```